# Getting the Name of href - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I am working on a project where I need to get the name of the href attribute to display it in the particular place using Inner.html.. I dont know how can I get the value of the name attribute..

HTML:

```
<p class="datarange"> 
    Select Date Range: 
    <a href="#" name="month" onclick="Lab()">Last Month </a>|
    <a href="#" name="2 weeks" onclick="Lab()"> Last 2 Weeks </a>|
    <a href="#" name="1 week" onclick="Lab()"> Last 1 Week</a>
</p>
```

Javascript :

```
function Lab()
{       
    var a = $(this).attr('href');       
    console.log(a)
    document.getElementById("lin").innerHTML="Last" +a;
}
```

Comment: *"I need to get the name of the href attribute"* The name of the `href` attribute is `href`. Do you want to get the name of the `a` element? FYI, inside your event handler, `this` refers to `window`, not the DOM element the handler is bound to.

Comment: Thanks for the info felix. Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(),
        var a = this.name;
        document.getElementById("lin").innerHTML="Last" +a;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" name="2 weeks" onclick="Lab(this);"> Last 2 Weeks </a>|
<a href="#" name="1 week" onclick="Lab(this);"> Last 1 Week</a>
```

- Pass the `this` to the **Lab** function.

JS:

```
function Lab(obj) {
    var name = obj.name
    console.log(name);
}
```

- You can check the console for the link name.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fKEt5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#lin").html("Last" +$(this).attr('name'));
```

As a side note why this `document.getElementById("lin")` when you have jquery with you.

use  `$("#lin")`

Answer (score 0):

You're currently getting the value of the `href` attribute. Change `'href'` to `'name'`

```
var a = $(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unobstrusive event handlers are preferred to inline, and you can get the name using `$(this).attr('name')`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        console.log( $(this).attr('name') );
        return false;
    });
});
```